# Update versus install differences

Tags: system-installation

When you perform an update rather than an install, do you retain your personal files and software installed? Also, any additional packages you applied to get a software application to function properly?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Updating vs installing what? software? The OS itself?

Comment: I am talking about updating versus installing of a new version of the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

***When you perform an update rather than an install, do you retain your personal files and software installed?***

Yes, of course. That's the whole point of doing that vs. a new installation that takes considerably less time and effort and also is "safer" because it's a clean install.

***any additional packages you applied to get a software application to function properly?***

From experience most of the user installed software will keep working fine.

Some might not and some may even prevent or break the online upgrade.

Some will be removed due to incompatibilities or missing dependencies in the new version of the OS.
It simply there isn't a one-size-fits-all answer.